# Ruby on Rails - Efficiency when inserting into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question that's probably mostly simple for many of you.

In my ruby on rails application, I'll be importing 20k+ rows of data into the database quite often. The component of the application that this happens in is taking a variable which contains the data in a list, loops through that, and does a new Model.create(data) on each line.

I've noticed that this can take a good 1.5 minutes or so for about 17k rows of data.

So essentially, it looks something similar to this:

```
@items = []
import_file = File.open('file')
data = import_file.read.split("\n")
data.each do |item|
   name = item.scan(/<name>(.*?)<\/name>)[0][0]
   address = item... etc
   @items << {
        :name => name,
        :address => address,
        etc
   }
end

@items.each do |row|
   Model.create(row)
end
```

When monitoring this in the rails server console, I can obviously see all 17k inserts, and it takes even longer for deleting when monitoring this in the console as well.

I'm sure this is very inefficient, so I've come to see if anyone has any suggestions or if this is just pretty normal for the amount of data that's being imported.

Comment: It is old but maybe still helpful: https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/

Comment: Thanks, but this is only inserting the same data over and over isn't it? All of the examples use "times.do"

Comment: Yes, in that example it is. The general idea there is to prepare an array of the values (almost like you did already) and create a single insert statement out of it, instead of calling create @items.length often.

Comment: Hmm. sorry I'm having a little trouble following you there. I understand what you mean in regards to using a single insert statement, but I think I'm stuck there.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the idea of the link mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way for such mass-/bulk-inserts seems to be [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import).
Someone has also made a [benchmark](http://www.piotrzadrozny.com/posts/bulk-insertion-of-data-with-activerecord-and-activerecord-import-gem) about it.

According to [the introductory example](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki#an-introductory-example) you could do something like this:

```
@items = []
import_file = File.open('file')
data = import_file.read.split("\n")
data.each do |item|
   name = item.scan(/<name>(.*?)<\/name>)[0][0]
   address = item... etc
   @items << Model.new(
        :name => name,
        :address => address,
        etc
   )
end

Model.import(@items)
```

The manual, single insert way:

```
@items = []
import_file = File.open('file')
data = import_file.read.split("\n")
data.each do |item|
   name = item.scan(/<name>(.*?)<\/name>)[0][0]
   address = item... etc
   @items << "(#{name}, #{address},...)"
end

sql = "INSERT INTO models (`name`, `address`, ...) VALUES #{@items.join(", ")}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Very cool. This worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot! Would you also happen to have any suggestions regarding importing mass data and still having the application be useful? Everything comes to a halt until that database import process is complete.

Comment: I can't really say anything about that. It is probably some hardware that is too slow to handle all the data. Maybe handling the data in chunks helps a bit but then again the import will need more time. If you don't want that you would have to find the hardware that is the bottle-neck and find a better replacement for that, I _think_.